# developing daily alarm in android

Tags: android, set, alarm, repeat

I have this piece of code that fire the alarm once by setting a time and date using the TimePicker and the DatePicker in another activity.
I want to modify it in a way that whenever I set a time and a date it will fire the alarm everyday at the same time. In other words I want the alarm to be fired daily.

```
public class M_ReminderManager {

    private Context mContext; 
    private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

    public M_ReminderManager(Context context) {
        mContext = context; 
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setReminder(Long reminderId, Calendar when) {

        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Medicines_OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID_MEDS, (long)reminderId); 

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
      }
}
```

I have tried using setRepeating function but I don't know how exactly I should set the attributes 
I used this line instead of the set function on the code but it didn't work:

```
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis() ,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pi);
```

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modify the code

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent)
```

in `AndroidAlarmService` class to

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5*1000, pendingIntent)
```

And read this link: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/schedule-repeating-alarm.html

Comment: you need to replace 5*1000 with AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY to set it daily

Comment: The method set(int, long, PendingIntent) in the type AlarmManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, long, long, PendingIntent)

Answer (score 1):

You can see this link: [How to run a service every day at noon, and on every boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845660/how-to-run-a-service-every-day-at-noon-and-on-every-boot/7846622#7846622)
You should remember to reset schedule on phone restart, link includes code for that aswell.