# Delete file on Android after 24h?

Tags: android

I´m a junior developer.I´m am bulding an app for Android.
My app will have audio files.But for this Audio you have to pay.The audio will disappear after 24h, then you have to pay again for the audio,always will be the sames audio files.The user will pay always form Google Play(somenthing like free and pro version).

How can I do this.Make a packge and then delete it,(i think this is not posibil).
I can do it with the function "delete" but what about the package?

Comment: use alarm and service to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You should use alarmmanager to set the 24h interval, you need to reset the alarm if the phone is shut down. See here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7846622/969325

But you have a problem with the file, you need to lock or hide it somehow so the user can't copy it and just keep it that way. I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks.Finaly I change my proyect.I don´t need to do that.