# How to start service at the particular time?

Tags: android, service

I am working on application in which I want to start service at the particular time.
I have stored the time in database table.
Now, I have the list of the time when service would be started.
So, how can I start service at all of these time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use android AlarmManager to schedule alarms.
you can register multiple alarms for your application.

hope this [link](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/43ddb901bd710fc6?hl=ja) helps you

Answer (score 1):

You want the Android Alarm Manager:

This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.

Hope this [link](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) helps you.

Comment: You should remember to reset the alarm when phone closes. Here is a stack link for an implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7846622/969325

Comment: @Warpzit Why should the OP reset the alarm? And what do you mean with "phone closes"?

Comment: @THelper everytime you shut down phone/the phone crashes/restarts ALL alarms will be lost, you need to set them again. To do this you store the alarms persistent and make a broadcastreceiver on phone startup.

Comment: @Warpzit In that case you are right.... I got confused by the word  "reset". Indeed the OP should write the alarms to file and restore them on startup.