# Restore Alarm manager after phone reboot

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager

i am building a small widget for learning purpose, it simply has an configuration activity where i set the update interval. it works normally and i can create multiple instance of it.
but when i reboot the phone the alarm manager stops, and the widget won't update.
after some search and google'ng i learned that i have to add a BOOT COMPLETE receiver 
but after several attempts i failed to implement so any one has an i idea about how to add that or any good source code example on widgets.

Comment: define "failed to implement". http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: what you mean by `i failed to implement` please elaborate...

Comment: i tried to add boot complet receiver similar to what warpitz answered but it didn't work... i don't have much time to fully understand the alarm manager concept as am short on time so tried few codes  that i got from searches but non worked

Comment: @user1844755 I had forgotten about a permission in the manifest, that has been added so it should work properly now.

Answer (score 7):

To do something at boot you simply do following.

First in the `manifest`, this is added under application tag:

```
    <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="packagename.ACTION"/>
        <action android:name="packagename.ACTION2"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name="BootSetter" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In order for this to work you need to add permission to receive the Broadcast in the manifest with following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Then you have a class BootSetter:

```
public class BootSetter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

There is a similar post, though not completly the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7846622/969325). It's about running an alarm every day at noon.

Comment: it is the stuff in the onRecieve that am having problem with.... what code i need to put in there to reactivate the alarm for all instances

Comment: @user1844755 You need to save the alarms in sharedpreference or some other persistent storage and then set them again, yes each and everyone of them. Just like you set them the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting  alarm manager in class other then `AppWidgetProvider` extended  class(widget class) .Better you should set an alarmmanager in **OnUpdate** method `AppWidgetProvider` extended class (widget class)then there will be no need of setting the alarm again after boot.