# Make application edit settings when application is not active. Android

Tags: java, android

I have an application that prompts the user to input a time value via timePicker.  I wrote the input into file using BufferedWriter.

I want my application to edit a user setting every day at the provided time.  I'm able to edit the setting using a function call in the app, but I do not know how to run this function when the application is not active.

How can I have the application run this function every day at the specified time even when the application is not active?

Comment: do you wanna to show your application to user every day at specified time to get input from him ?

Comment: No, once the user enters the value there should be no further prompt.

Comment: you can go for alarm Manager or services.. first check whether your app is in foreground or not.. as per that call it

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845660/how-to-run-a-service-every-day-at-noon-and-on-every-boot

Answer (score 3):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) (or even an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) if you need user interaction) at the specified time. Then simply put the code for editing your settings in the Service or BroadcastReceiver.