# start repeating alarm from AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to start a service every day from 8am to 6pm. I am using 3 alarms.

1. For starting alarm2 everyday at 8am.
2. For starting service every 1 min.
3. To stop alarm2.

Is it the proper way? Also I am unable to start alarm2 from alarm1.

This is code for alarm 1:

```
    public class AlarmReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {
        int interval;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent in=new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver2);
            PendingIntent startingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,in, 0);

            long duration = interval * 60 * 1000;
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeOn.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000,startingIntent);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Far from enough code to tell if it has been set up properly. There is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7846622/969325) on how you should set up the AlarmManager. I'd recommend looking it through if there is something you've missed.

Also as you can see in the example you gotta reset the Alarms every time the phone is rebooted. If you don't the services will not run.