# Android - show notification at specific date

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

I want to show a notification at a specific date and I use Calendar object:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds);
    long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

And I use a AlarmManager:

```
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationsService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
    am.cancel(pi);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pi);
```

But this not show a correct miliseconds, if I use:

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, pi);
```

Show correct notification, but if I use a **when** flag not show a correct miliseconds to notification. Why? Someone help me please. thanks

**Edit**: (Solve problem)

The problem was that the Month in Calendar is previous at actual (January = 0, February = 1, ...)

Comment: Use alarm manager to fire the code at a particular date and time

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking here for an example of how to run a service at a specific date/time: [How to run a service every day at noon, and on every boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845660/how-to-run-a-service-every-day-at-noon-and-on-every-boot/7846622#7846622)

One important thing you gotta remember with alarmmanager is that all values are forgotten on phone restart. Link provides a solution for that as well.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know about alarmmanager fails. But this link don't help me, because I can show notification in a specific date (Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds) and this link have code to every days. I don't want use "AlarmManager.setRepeating..." I want "AlarmManager.set...", thanks

Comment: Thanks, I solve the problem. The problem was that the Month in Calendar is previous at actual (January = 0, February = 1, ...)