# How to insert data in sqlite once in a day at specific time in android in backgroud?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, alarmmanager

My task is to insert or update some specific data in sqlite based on some condition at 10:00 daily in background. I am stuck. Please Help.

Comment: without any code how to help you..

Comment: How to develop a service that runs in background at specific time once in a day..this will resolve my issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845660/how-to-run-a-service-every-day-at-noon-and-on-every-boot this should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `YourReceiver.java` file,

```
class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().matches(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)) {
            if (check_your_time_with_system_time) {
                // update your DB here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register your `Receiver` in manifest.xml.

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The `onReceive()` method of `YourReceiver` will be called every minute.