# Android Studio Start Method every day

Tags: android, android-studio, service, alarmmanager

I am working on some project and i want to do some method that Every day in specific time do something.
I was made the method and it's run perfectly, the only problem is start the method every day in specific hour.

I am really confused between

*AlaramManger
*Serives and etc

How do you suggest to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `AlarmManager` to accomplish it. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7846622/4244598).

Comment: Ok, so this work, but i can't start my method i get : on a null object reference. mean that it's not determined.
How can i start method from AlaramReciver? 
For example:
MainActivity a1 = new MainActivity;
a1.startMethod();